# iOS Snapchat SDK crashes after fresh cocoapods install

Tags: ios, swift, snapchat

I can't make SnapSDK to work on iOS. I just installed via cocoapods and it crashes in both CreativeKit and LoginKit. I also created a brand new project and it reproduces there too.

Cocoapods integration:

```
pod 'SnapSDK', :subspecs => ['SCSDKLoginKit', 'SCSDKCreativeKit', 'SCSDKBitmojiKit']
```

My code:

```
SCSDKLoginClient.login(from: self, completion: { success, error in
      print("I wish it would reach here")

    })
```

Error thrown:

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Stack:

```
Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x000000010b96f3fd in _dispatch_once_wait.cold.1 ()
#1  0x000000010b93d63c in _dispatch_once_wait ()
#2  0x000000010b8bd0ac in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol71$$SCSDKCoreKit ()
#3  0x000000010b8bd309 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol74$$SCSDKCoreKit ()
#4  0x000000010b8bd0e0 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol72$$SCSDKCoreKit ()
#5  0x000000010b93cd48 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#6  0x000000010b93e297 in _dispatch_once_callout ()
#7  0x000000010b8bd0ac in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol71$$SCSDKCoreKit ()
#8  0x000000010b8ba3fb in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol10$$SCSDKCoreKit ()
#9  0x000000010b91d6e7 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol56$$SCSDKLoginKit ()
#10 0x000000010b91d5b8 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol54$$SCSDKLoginKit ()
#11 0x000000010b91aa9b in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol1$$SCSDKLoginKit ()
#12 0x000000010b924b64 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol221$$SCSDKLoginKit ()
#13 0x000000010b4c0cd4 in MasterViewController.insertNewObject(_:) at /Users/.../SnapTest/MasterViewController.swift:38
#14 0x000000010b4c0ee0 in @objc MasterViewController.insertNewObject(_:) ()
#15 0x00007fff47850dfa in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] ()
#16 0x00007fff46e78f06 in __45-[_UIButtonBarTargetAction _invoke:forEvent:]_block_invoke ()
#17 0x00007fff46e78d74 in -[_UIButtonBarTargetAction _invoke:forEvent:] ()
#18 0x00007fff47850dfa in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] ()
#19 0x00007fff4722ac22 in -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] ()
#20 0x00007fff4722af6c in -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] ()
#21 0x00007fff47229ecb in -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] ()
#22 0x00007fff4788bc1d in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] ()
#23 0x00007fff4788d524 in -[UIWindow sendEvent:] ()
#24 0x00007fff47868427 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#25 0x00007fff478e987e in __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue ()
#26 0x00007fff478ec344 in __handleEventQueueInternal ()
#27 0x00007fff23bb2221 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#28 0x00007fff23bb214c in __CFRunLoopDoSource0 ()
#29 0x00007fff23bb1924 in __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()
#30 0x00007fff23bac62f in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#31 0x00007fff23babe16 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#32 0x00007fff38438bb0 in GSEventRunModal ()
#33 0x00007fff4784fb48 in UIApplicationMain ()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I was missing some .plist keys.

> **Getting started**
> Add the following fields in your application’s
> Info.plist file.
>
> Required:
>
> `SCSDKClientId` (string): Your application’s client ID
>
> `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` (string-array): Must contain `snapchat`